# How to write code in python (from a vb net guy)

Tags: python

I am used to vb.net. I am learning python 3.6/7, as I understand it code writing is in either:

1. functions that return a result
2. functions that return a None
3. In a modules (no functions), ie run the module.py
4. In a class ie run the class.ID.function (ref (1) and (2))

In .Net you can run code in a function and a sub routine, so python has no sub routines, just functions returning None.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are right, Python doesn't distinguishes between functions and sub routines, procedures etc. and uses None if the return value is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Every function in python return some value, if you don't specify the return value then it will implicitly return None. So there is no distinction like sub or function in python.

Comment: My post was not about 'Return None'. it was more about where code sits in the python language, where code can be placed

Answer (score 1):

Like other programming languages, in Python:

> To let a function return a value, you have to use the return statement.

But if you don't specify the return value then it will simply return Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, *In computer programming, a subroutine is a sequence of program instructions that performs a specific task, packaged as a unit. This unit can then be used in programs wherever that particular task should be performed.* 
So, in python a function can return any kind of value, objects or even None. A function returns None in two cases :

1. You write `return None` or `return` at the end of the function.

```
def some_func():
    #do anything and return None
    #you can write "return" instead "return None"
    return None

some_var = some_func()
#There is no output to the above line of code

print(some_var)
#There is no output to the above line of code

print(type(some_var))
#Output: NoneType
```

2. You don't return anything at all and every function by default returns a None if nothing specified. For example:

```
def some_func():
    print ("I print and return nothing")

some_var = some_func()
#Output : I print and return nothing

print(some_var)
#There is no output to the above line of code

print(type(some_var))
#Output: NoneType
```

Hope it helps.